# Python BeautifulSoup City Scraping Complications

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape the countries and cities off craigslist and i am so close.

The problem i am having is that the cities skip and go to the next box.

The output i am trying to achieve is:

```
COUNTRY   |    STATE   |   CITY
US:          ALABAMA:       AUBURN
US:          ALABAMA:       BIRMINGHAM
US:          ALABAMA:       DOTHAN
```

But instead i get:

```
COUNTRY   |    STATE   |   CITY
US:          ALABAMA:       AUBURN
US:          ALABAMA:       ANCHORAGE / MAT-SU
US:          ALABAMA:       FLAGSTAFF / SEDONA
```

Then when i reach the end of the column, the STATE changes to the next STATE.

This is my current code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites").read())
soup.prettify()

for h1 in soup.findAll('h1'):
    colmask_div = h1.findNextSibling('div')

    for box_div in colmask_div.findAll('div'):
        h4 = box_div.find('h4')

        for ul in box_div.findAll('ul'):
            print'{} : {} : {}'.format(h1.text, h4.text, ul.li.a.text)
            raw_input()
```

Skipping boxes somewhere but can't find where! Thanks. This is not homework, just a personal project to learn beautifulsoup :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are:

1. Getting the first `h4` element (state name) in the column
2. Getting all the `ul` elements (lists of towns) in the whole column
3. For each list of towns, outputting the first `li` element (town name) only
4. Moving on to the next list of towns, without moving on to the next state

I'd go for something more like this:

```
for country in soup.findAll('h1'):
    country_data = country.findNextSibling('div')
    for state, towns in zip(country_data.findAll('h4'), country_data.findAll('ul')):
        for town in towns.findAll('li'):
            print '{} : {} : {}'.format(country.text, state.text, town.text)
            raw_input()
```

You don't need to process each column in turn.  Here I am getting BS to do the work of fetching all the nested `h4` and `ul` elements in the top level `div` for a country as two lists.

I then use the python [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function to iterate over those two lists in step.

---

#### Output

```
US : Alabama : auburn
US : Alabama : birmingham
US : Alabama : dothan
...
US : Alabama : tuscaloosa
US : Alaska : anchorage / mat-su
...
US : Territories : U.S. virgin islands
Canada : Alberta : calgary
...
```

---

#### Performance

In Python 2, you could improve the performance of this code by using [`itertools.izip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip).  This doesn't create the whole list of pairs of elements in memory from the two inputs, but uses a generator instead.

In Python 3, the regular [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) function does this by default.